# Using stack for profiling

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to do some profiling using `stack --enable-profiling` and I'm a bit confused about what's happening exactly.

Do I need to use also `--enable-library` ?.
Also, is it build in a separate directory ?What happend next I build it, will remember that am I in *profiling mode* or do I have to use the `--enable-profiling` all the time.

It is generally recommended to profile in conjonction with the `-O2` option. Does `--enable-profiling` set it automatically ?

Answer (score 5):

Stack support for enabling profiling works great, example:

```
stack build --profile --executable-profiling --library-profiling
stack exec -- example <your prog args> +RTS -p
```

Then see example.prof for the default output.

**Update**: the stack support pointed me to the right correct for exec, see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1655

Comment: does this set `-O2` ? how

Comment: No - I would not think so - why would it? I would set this in the .cabal file, but there is probably a stack option for that, too.

Comment: Because it's a good practice to profile optimised version of the code. I don't want it in the cabal file because it don't need it when I am developing.

Comment: Point taken. In the [docs](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#exec) are examples for setting ghc options on the command line. This should override the .cabal settings. I have not tested that though.

Comment: FYI looks like the answer is a little redundant: `stack build --profile` implies `--enable-library-profiling` and `--enable-executable-profiling`: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#debugging